# Merge arrays with Sum specific value keys

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

If someone has already done it, the idea is to merge different arrays into one and also merge the values `sum` of `price, qty` only for the identical keys.

In my example I only put two arrays to be merged `$arr1, $arr2` but the idea is to do it dynamically because I do not have a defined number of arrays , I can have 2 as I can have 15.

**Example:**

```
<?php

$arr1 = [
    51 => [
        'name' => 'p1',
        'price' => '20',
        'qty' => '10',
        'category' => 'c1'
    ],
    
    3 => [
        'name' => 'p2',
        'price' => '10.50',
        'qty' => '3',
        'category' => 'c2'
    ]
];
    
$arr2 = [
    3 => [
        'name' => 'p3',
        'price' => '23',
        'qty' => '22',
        'category' => 'c1'
    ],
    
    102 => [
        'name' => 'p4',
        'price' => '10.50',
        'qty' => '8',
        'category' => 'c2'
    ]
    
];
```

Code :

```
mergeArrays(($arr1 + $arr2));



function mergeArrays($array)
{
    $mergedArray = [];
    foreach ($array as $k => $arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            if (!isset($mergedArray[$key])) {
                $mergedArray[$k][$key] = $value;
            } else {
                $mergedArray[$key] += $value;
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($mergedArray);
    //return $mergedArray;
}
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [51] => Array
        (
            [name] => p1
            [price] => 20
            [qty] => 10
            [category] => c1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => p2
            [price] => 10.50
            [qty] => 3
            [category] => c2
        )

    [102] => Array
        (
            [name] => p4
            [price] => 10.50
            [qty] => 8
            [category] => c2
        )

)
```

**Expected result:**

```
Array
(
    [51] => Array
        (
            [name] => p1
            [price] => 20
            [qty] => 10
            [category] => c1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => p3       // the last erray value
            [price] => 33.50   //sum
            [qty] => 25        //sum
            [category] => c1   // the last erray value
        )

    [102] => Array
        (
            [name] => p4
            [price] => 10.50
            [qty] => 8
            [category] => c2
        )

)
```

Comment: Not sure I understand why you would merge the [3] arrays as the Name is not the same in those 2 seperate occurances? The prices are different, and you picked the smallest?

Comment: @RiggsFolly to answer your first question, in my case the `name` is not a problem if they are not identical, my need is to sum `[price]` and `[qty]` when first keys are identical, `[3]` in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `...$in` to indicate any number of arrays can be passed to the function and then a couple of loops will do the job for you

```
$arr1 = [  51 => [  'name' => 'p1', 'price' => '20', 'qty' => '10', 'category' => 'c1' ],
            3 => [  'name' => 'p2', 'price' => '10.50', 'qty' => '3',  'category' => 'c2' ]
    ];
    
$arr2 = [  3 => [ 'name' => 'p3',  'price' => '23', 'qty' => '22', 'category' => 'c1'  ],
         102 => [ 'name' => 'p4',  'price' => '10.50', 'qty' => '8', 'category' => 'c2' ]
    ];

function myMerge(Array ...$in)
{
    $new = $in[0];

    for($i=1; $i<count($in); $i++){
        foreach($in[$i] as $idx => &$a) {
            if( isset($new[$idx]) ){
                $new[$idx]['qty'] += $a['qty'];
                $new[$idx]['price'] += $a['price'];
            } else {
                $new[$idx] = $a;
            }
        }
    }        
    return $new;
}

print_r( myMerge($arr1, $arr2) );
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [51] => Array
        (
            [name] => p1
            [price] => 20
            [qty] => 10
            [category] => c1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => p2
            [price] => 33.5
            [qty] => 25
            [category] => c2
        )

    [102] => Array
        (
            [name] => p4
            [price] => 10.50
            [qty] => 8
            [category] => c2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps

```
    <?php
$arr1 = [
    51 => [
        'name' => 'p1',
        'price' => '20',
        'qty' => '10',
        'category' => 'c1'
    ],
    
    3 => [
        'name' => 'p2',
        'price' => '10.50',
        'qty' => '3',
        'category' => 'c2'
    ]
];
    
$arr2 = [
    3 => [
        'name' => 'p3',
        'price' => '23',
        'qty' => '22',
        'category' => 'c1'
    ],
    
    102 => [
        'name' => 'p4',
        'price' => '10.50',
        'qty' => '8',
        'category' => 'c2'
    ]
    
];
$result = [];
foreach([$arr1, $arr2] as $arr) {
 $keysFromCurrentArray = array_keys($arr);
 foreach ($keysFromCurrentArray as $key) {
     if(array_key_exists($key, $result)) {
        $result[$key] = [
            $result[$key]['name'] = $arr[$key]['name'],
            $result[$key]['price'] += $arr[$key]['price'],
            $result[$key]['qty'] += $arr[$key]['qty'],
            $result[$key]['category'] = $arr[$key]['category'],
        ];
     }  else {
        $result[$key] = $arr[$key];
     }
 }
 
}

var_export($result);
```

output :

```
array (
  51 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'p1',
    'price' => '20',
    'qty' => '10',
    'category' => 'c1',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 'p3',
    1 => 33.5,
    2 => 25,
    3 => 'c1',
  ),
  102 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'p4',
    'price' => '10.50',
    'qty' => '8',
    'category' => 'c2',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using array merge in loop is NOT optimal

You can put arrays in one like this:

```
$arrays = [ [1, 2], [2, 3], [5,8] ];
```

And then:

```
$merged = array_merge([], ...$arrays);
```

Comment: And what about accululating the Qty and Price

Comment: After merge them you have one array that the array_keys are unique, use it in loop